# Can I change an attribute name from a table derived from a type?

Tags: sql, oracle, object-oriented-database

Folowing the Object-Relational Database model, I wanted to create the tables `or_doctor` and `or_recepcionist` derived from the type `t_employee`.
Here, follows the type structure:

```
DROP TYPE t_employee FORCE;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_employee AS OBJECT (
    num_employee INTEGER,
    name_employee VARCHAR2(50),
    birthdate_employee DATE
);
```

And here, the tables' structure:

```
DROP TABLE or_doctor CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE or_doctor OF t_employee (
    PRIMARY KEY (num_employee),
    name_employee NOT NULL,
    birthdate_employee NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;

DROP TABLE or_recepcionist CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
CREATE TABLE or_recepcionist OF t_employee (
    PRIMARY KEY (num_employee),
    name_employee NOT NULL,
    birthdate_employee NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

Doing so, the attributes names, on both tables, will end up with "employee". Could I change the attribute name so they are specific in each table at the moment I'm creating the table?
E.G.:

Table `or_doctor: num_doct, name_doct, birthdate_doct`.
Table `or_recepcionist: num_recep, name_recep, birthdate_recep`.

Comment: Why separate tables for doctors and receptionists?

Comment: @June7, because in Brazil, doctors have a license called CRM (could be compared to USMLE from USA) and, as I see, this attribute must be NOT NULL to register a doctor into a hospital database, whereas a recepcionist registration does not need it.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to leave the field Null for non-doctor employees - "Normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it works". There are only 2 types of employees?

Comment: @June7 yes, only 2. It's for a homework haha. But still, I had to ask. I'm new to Object-Relational DB.

Comment: Well, name or name_employee as field name - really no difference because both tables still hold employee info. So with that view, there was nothing wrong with your structure and code. And unless the homework requires creating these 2 tables just to demonstrate applying technique, see no compelling reason to split data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a frame challenge, don't add a suffix to your identifiers then you don't need to worry about the suffix being incorrect:

```sql
CREATE TYPE t_employee AS OBJECT (
    num       INTEGER,
    name      VARCHAR2(50),
    birthdate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE or_doctor OF t_employee (
    PRIMARY KEY (num),
    name      NOT NULL,
    birthdate NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;

CREATE TABLE or_receptionist OF t_employee (
    PRIMARY KEY (num),
    name      NOT NULL,
    birthdate NOT NULL
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS SYSTEM GENERATED;
```

If you try to rename the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE or_doctor RENAME COLUMN name TO name_doctor;
```

Then you will get the error:

```
ORA-23291: Only base table columns may be renamed
```

If you are using object-derived tables then you appear to be stuck with the identifiers from the object; so, make the object names generic so that they are appropriate in every place they are going to be used.

Comment: How is this different from using name_employee or birthdate_employee? Are you saying what the OP wants is not possible?

Comment: @June7 No, I don't believe it is possible. The [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) does not appear to allow it and `ALTER TABLE .... RENAME COLUMN` raises an exception.

Comment: Ah, I now understand what is happening. Thank you.